# 320x480 div, how to make it scale on all phones?

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, scale, viewport, meta

At the moment I'm using the following viewport code with a 320x480 portrait phone ad:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

For me, it scales well on an iPhone3, iPhone3GS, iPhone4, iPhone4S, iPhone5, Samsung galaxy S3, a Sony Erricson phone and so on

The agency who is serving these ads need it to work on all phones and tell us that it's not scaling, but wont offer which devices it wont scale on :/

Is there anything else I can do in regards to that meta viewport tag to ensure it scales to the width of a device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Opera mobile emulator'. You can find series of various mobile device testing environment with different screen width. This really helps while you are developing responsive sites